# CDI injection with bean-discovery-mode="annotated"

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a web application deployed on Glassfish 4 that allows me to select an interface implementation at injection point. However, when I try to deploy I am getting a **org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException**. The problem originates from the fact that I have not explicitly specified the injection class with a CDI decoration. Assuming I wanted to use **javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped** to which ever class is requiring the decoration and I **DO NOT** want to use **bean-discovery-mode="all"**. Which class/method should I be decorating?

**beans.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

**The interface:**

```
public interface ModelQuery {
...
}
```

**The implementation:**

```
public class DasModelQuery implements ModelQuery {
...
}
```

**The Qualifier:**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface ModelQueryQualifier {
}
```

**The ModelQueryType:**

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface ModelQueryType {
...
}
```

**The Factory:**

```
public class ModelQueryFactory {

    @Produces
    @ModelQueryQualifier
    public ModelQuery getModelQuery(
            @Any Instance<ModelQuery> instance, 
            InjectionPoint ip){
        Annotated gtAnnotated = ip.getAnnotated();
        ModelQueryType gtAnnotation = gtAnnotated.getAnnotation(ModelQueryType.class);
        Class<? extends ModelQuery> modelService = gtAnnotation.value().getClazz();
        return instance.select(modelService).get();
    }

}
```

**The Injection:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Das implements Serializable {
...
    @Inject
    @ModelQueryQualifier
    @ModelQueryType(ModelQueryType.ModelQueries.DAS)
    private ModelQuery model;
...
}
```

**The Exception:**

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [ModelQuery] with qualifiers [@ModelQueryQualifier] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @ModelQueryQualifier @ModelQueryType private com.service.das.Das.model]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:325)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:208)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:519)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:505)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:480)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your factory isn't annotated.  In order for it to be resolved, the class needs to be annotated, e.g. `@Dependent` or `@ApplicationScoped`

Comment: I tried annotating with @RequestScoped but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Why `@RequestScoped`? Your bean is `@ViewScoped` which doesn't implicitly have an active request behind it.  You must use either `@Dependent` or `@ApplicationScoped`